# How can I draw over the notification bar?

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, android-notification-bar

I need to draw a rectangle that is drawn over the notification bar, but I'm unable to get it to work. The code looks like this:

```
canvas.drawRect(0,0, 200, 200, mLoadPaint);
```

But `0, 0` is just bellow the notification bar, instead of over it. How can I draw over the notification bar?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the theme of your Activity to something like this one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen

```
<activity class="AddRssItem" android:label="Add an item" android:theme="@android:style/....
```